# dataframe to csv missing column name for index

Tags: python, pandas

When writing the pandas mainTable dataframe to `mainTable.csv`, but after the file is written the name of the column for `index` is missing.
Why does this happen since I have specified `index=True`?

```
mainTable.to_csv(r'/Users/myuser/Completed/mainTable.csv',index=True)
mainTable = pd.read_csv('mainTable.csv')
print(mainTable.columns)


 MacBook-Pro:Completed iliebogdanbarbulescu$ python map.py
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'name', 'iso_a3', 'geometry', 'iso_code', 'continent']

print output
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

save with `index_label='Index_name'`, since by default `index_label=None`.
See for pandas' `.csv()` method : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

```
mainTable.to_csv(r'/Users/myuser/Completed/mainTable.csv',index=True, index_label='Index_name')
```